# Performance gap using sub query with STGeomFromText

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, geometry, point

I'm using a geometric table, with polygons inside.

The problem is the point I try to match is stored in a table, and I can't get the same performance using one query instead of two :

```
-- this is the base / best time
SELECT *
FROM dbo.table1
WHERE geomField.STContains(
    GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(
        'POINT(6.82 7.21)'
        ,0)
    ) = 1

-- this is more or less the same as the previous
DECLARE @g GEOMETRY = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(
        (select top 1 'POINT(6.82 7.21)')
        ,0);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.table1
WHERE geomField.STContains(@g) = 1

-- this is slow as hell
SELECT *
FROM dbo.table1
WHERE geomField.STContains(
    GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText(
        (select top 1 'POINT(6.82 7.21)')
        ,0)
    ) = 1
```

Is there any way to improve the last one ? (I'm using `EXEC sp_executesql` in the backend and the 2nd option mean a stored procedure)

Comment: Is the point in the other table really stored as text (i.e. `POINT(6.82 7.21)`) or is it stored as a geography data type? If the former, my guess is that you're running afoul of it running that conversion to geography for every row in table1. There may be ways around that, but just trying to understand the problem first.

Comment: @BenThul the point is stored as a geometric datatype, as you can see I use `geomField.STContains()`. But the fact that there is a `SELECT` to do seem to mess-up the query engine

Comment: I'm more talking about the `STGeomFromText` call that you're making in the query. where is that point coming from?

Comment: @BenThul oh, I see your point. I've got string of X and Y in my table to match again table1, so I need to make the convert `STGeomFromText()`, but I'll try this : `STContains((SELECT TOP 1 GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText((select top 1 'POINT(6.82 7.21)'),0))) = 1` it may avoid the `STGeomFromText` for each line.

Comment: You're likely already trying some things, but one thing I'd try myself is doing the conversion of your point's WKT → geometry in a common table expression and then referencing that in your query.